# Cannot enable CORS in Laravel API?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, cors

I am trying to build a simple Angular application. I have created an API in Laravel which has only two simple routes which send back airports and flights json data. I have configured my Angular application to fetch the data by a service like so:

**services.js**

```
angular.module('airlineServices', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('Airport', function($resource){
        return $resource("http://angulair.rohanchhabra.in/airports/:id", {}, {
            query: { method: "GET", isArray: false }
        });
    });
```

Now when I use the resource as a simple json file placed in the angular directory itself, it works. But when I try to fetch the the data from the Laravel API from my service as in the code above, I see an error in the console which says:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://angulair.rohanchhabra.in/airports. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

I have installed a package https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors which is supposed to enable CORS. The config file looks like so:

```
<?php

return array(

    /*
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     | Laravel CORS Defaults
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |
     | The defaults are the default values applied to all the paths that match,
     | unless overridden in a specific URL configuration.
     | If you want them to apply to everything, you must define a path with *.
     |
     | allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders and allowedMethods can be set to array('*') 
     | to accept any value, the allowed methods however have to be explicitly listed.
     |
     */
    'defaults' => array(
        'supportsCredentials' => false,
        'allowedOrigins' => array('*'),
        'allowedHeaders' => array('*'),
        'allowedMethods' => array('*'),
        'exposedHeaders' => array(),
        'maxAge' => 0,
        'hosts' => array(),
    ),

    'paths' => array(
        'api/*' => array(
            'allowedOrigins' => array('*'),
            'allowedHeaders' => array('*'),
            'allowedMethods' => array('*'),
            'maxAge' => 3600,
        ),
        '*' => array(
            'allowedOrigins' => array('*'),
            'allowedHeaders' => array('Content-Type'),
            'allowedMethods' => array('POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE'),
            'maxAge' => 3600,
            'hosts' => array('api.*'),
        ),
    ),

);
```

I have even tried to add code in the App:after() in filters.php like so:

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    return $response;
});
```

Even this did not help. So I went ahead and tried editing the .htaccess file like so:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

I am still getting the same error.

If the code I have mentioned above does not help, I have made both the repositories public so that everyone can have a look:

[Laravel API](http://gitlab.learningtechasia.com:8901/rohan0793/angulairapi.git)

[Angular Application](http://gitlab.learningtechasia.com:8901/rohan0793/angulair.git)

What am I doing wrong? How can I enable CORS so that I can consume the API from any remote application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ngResource URL needs to be changed. This should work:

```
return $resource("http://angulairapi.rohanchhabra.in/airports", {}, {
    query: { method: "GET", isArray: false }
});
```

---

<s>You need Your ngResource URL needs to allow the OPTIONS header be changed. See https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/laravel-5-cors-headers-with-filters</s>

Quote from the page This should work:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    // Enable CORS 
    // In production, replace * with http://yourdomain.com 
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');

    ifreturn $resource(Request:"http:getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
        // The client-side application can set only headers allowed angulairapi.rohanchhabra.in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token/airports", Origin{}, Authorization'
        ];{
        return Response:query:make('You are connected to the{ API',method: 200"GET", $headers);
  isArray: false }
});
```

I haven't used laravel-cors myself, but alternatively, you might want to try and add OPTIONS to your paths:

```
'*' => array(
    'allowedOrigins' => array('*'),
    'allowedHeaders' => array('Content-Type'),
    'allowedMethods' => array('POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'),
    'maxAge' => 3600,
    'hosts' => array('api.*'),
),
```

Comment: Although I don't understand the code, I have updated App::before as you suggested. Still no luck.

Comment: Angular ngResource sends an OPTIONS request prior to sending a GET/POST/PUT/DELETE. This is a way for clients to know what HTTP methods are allowed.

Can you perhaps pull up a REST client and check if you're even getting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response?

Comment: Oh, makes more sense now! But what do you suggest I do now?

Comment: Also, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_allowmethods.html - perhaps Apache is blocking the OPTIONS method.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials → true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *
Postman REST client

Comment: I don't understand the second thing you wish me to try?

Comment: What HTTP method did you use from Postman? Can you please try OPTIONS, if you haven't already? And I did a bit more fiddling - looks like Apache by default should allow the OPTIONS method.

Are you able to reach your API when you do a $http.get('http://...', <callback>) from angular, instead of using ngResource?

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials →true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers →X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods →POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*

Comment: I'll try the $http now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67406/discussion-between-sayak-banerjee-and-rohan).